# Facebook authentication failure in release apk in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, release

I have developed and tested my android app on several devices and emulators. Right now I am going to release my app, so I created a signed apk of my android app. But the problem is that in this release apk the facebook authentication is not working.

While I am trying to login with facebook it shows the key hash does not exists, please add this `xxxxxx` key hash. This problem exists even after adding the provided hash key.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?
How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are using your signed apk's key hash?

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VJ1rRxiAEY) on how to create keyhash of a signed apk. The KeyHash for Signed apk differs from the KeyHash used during debugging. I Hope it helps you.

Comment: @ljpv14 I created my keystore from android studio and signed my app with that. Is not this the correct way to sign an app?

Comment: Keystore is different from key hash. Once you have signed it, you need to create a new keyhash because the keyhash you have during debug is different once you have signed your application. You may refer to @Arshak 's link Also make sure that you also change the keyhash into your signed apk's keyhash that your facebook application android platform on facebook developer console is using. You might have forgot to replace it with the signed ones.